# Keeping same numbering as in the main file in standalone files

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, templates, overleaf

I am creating standalone documents for Frontiers as it wants tables in a separate file.
However, I cannot keep numeration (for example, table 3 in the document, it is Table 1 in this file). Do you know how I can keep numeration as in label?

```
\documentclass[utf8]{frontiersHLTH} % for Health articles

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{url,hyperref,lineno,microtype,subcaption}
\linenumbers

\usepackage{makecell}


\begin{document}

\def\keyFont{\fontsize{8}{11}\helveticabold }
\def\firstAuthorLast{Sample} 
\def\Authors{}


%%%TABLE%%%
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{tabular}{ cccccc } 
\hline
& c1 & c2 & c3 & c4 c5 & c6 & c7 \\
\hline
Example 1 & 12 & 32 & 12 & 43 & 12 \\ 
Example 2 & 12 & 21 & 41 & 43 & 21\\  
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:x1} \small Example of caption}
\end{table}
}

\end{document}
```

Here the template (if you need it): https://it.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-frontiers-journal/myxxkvjwqhrv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With overleaf, this is what I use to crossreference object between subfiles. Define the following command in your preambles :

```
\newcommand*{\myexternaldocument}[1]{%
    \externaldocument{#1}%
    \addFileDependency{#1.tex}%
    \addFileDependency{#1.aux}%
}
```

And if in `file1`, you need to crossref an element from `file2`, just add in your preamble :

```
\myexternaldocument{file2}
```

In Overleaf, you also need to define a file `latexmkrc` in your root folder :

```
# This is file is necessary for corss referencing when using overleaf 

add_cus_dep( 'tex', 'aux', 0, 'makeexternaldocument' );

sub makeexternaldocument {
    # if the dependency isn't one of the files that this latexmk run will consider, process it
    # without this test, we would get an infinite loop!
    if (!($root_filename eq $_[0]))
    {   # PLEASE ENABLE ONLY ONE OF THE FOLLOWING
        # DEPENDING ON THE ENGINE YOU'RE USING
    
        # FOR PDFLATEX
        system( "latexmk -pdf \"$_[0]\"" );

        # FOR LATEX+DVIPDF
        # system( "latexmk \"$_[0]\"" );

        # FOR XELATEX
        # system( "latexmk -xelatex \"$_[0]\"" );
        
        # FOR LUALATEX
        # system( "latexmk -lualatex \"$_[0]\"" );
   }
}
```

Your MWE is not complete so I could not test if that really worked in your specific example. But I do not see why it should not. Have a look at this also : https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf

Note that you need to compile `file2` at least once before you compile `file1` in my example above so that the `file1.aux` can be created.